# i want to add a break or new line to an XML which i am forming using CDataXMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xml

I would like to add a break or new line to `XML` which I am forming using `CDataXMLStreamWriter`

I tried below code but it didn't worked.

```
CDataXMLStreamWriter cdataStreamWriter = null;
cdataStreamWriter.writeCharacters("\n");
```

Please give me some suggestion on this.

Comment: Why? line terminators aren't significant in XML.

Comment: I have no idea on line terminators. please suggest which is best solution to  insert a line break in XML using CDataXMLStreamWriter